# HTML object tag giving one line space

Tags: css, html

I want to use an html object tag in my application, but I dont want to give it any width or height.

Now when I render the page, it gives me one line space.

I have used the following CSS properties to eliminate this space but nothing is working

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
```

Can somebody please tell me why I am continuously having this one line space?

Comment: which/all browsers? screen shot & code snippet pls.

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net to post HTML+CSS sample.


It sounds like you may want to apply CSS reset, though. These ones are good: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following style proprties to my html object tag and it resolved the problem

opacity:1;background-color:#000000;width:0px;height:0px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; font-size:0px; top:-50px; border:none;